# Quick & Simple GUI Lib for Windows?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've looked around and discovered Tkinter, however learning everything for Tk for my current needs (just a simple text input, textbox and an image) doesn't seem worth it. Any better alternative?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used a library called guizero that is great and easy to use for a low-complexity GUI. You can install it with `pip install guizero` and the documentation can be found at https://lawsie.github.io/guizero/start/ Best of luck! (Yes, I know recommendations are off-topic)